# Sort a string array based on a corresponding integer array

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

Say I'm given a string array, each string has a corresponding weight. So for example:

```
str_arr = ["james", "blake", "rob"]
weights = [4, 7, 1]
```

str_arr[i] corresponds to weights[i].

How would I go about sorting str_arr in ascending order with respect to weights? For example:

(after sorting) weights would be `[1, 4, 7]` which corresponds to str_arr = `["rob", "james", "blake"]`

How do I get `["rob", "james", "blake"]`?

Most sorting comparators deal with modifying the way the sorting on the current array works, and I looked into sorting with respect to the existing order of a different array--but I'm not sure how to sort the integer array and simultaneously do the same with the str_arr based on the output of the integer array...Is there a Rubyist way of doing this?

Comment: The Ruby way would be using a Hash instead of arrays {james: 4, blake: 7, ..} , sort on the weight value and use the the .keys method to have your array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) and [`with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index):

```
str_arr.sort_by.with_index { |_, i| weights[i] }
#=> ["rob", "james", "blake"]
```

Comment: I've seen it (used at least once by @ArupRakshit, if memory serves) and was trying to remember it... Yes, the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following with parallel assignment:

```
str_arr, weights = str_arr.zip(weights).sort_by(&:last).transpose
#=> [["rob", "james", "blake"], [1, 4, 7]]

str_arr #=> ["rob", "james", "blake"] 
weights #=> [1, 4, 7]
```

Key methods: [Array#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-zip), [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) and [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose).

Comment: This wouldn't work in the case that one of the weights was missing, correct?

Comment: Reverse the order, and you don't need `sort_by` : `weights.zip(str_arr).sort.transpose`

Comment: @Sunny not sure what you mean. How would an array with a missing weight look?

Answer (score 1):

```
str_arr.values_at(*weights.size.times.sort_by { |i| weights[i] })
  #=> ["rob", "james", "blake"]
```

The two steps are as follows.

```
a = weights.size.times.sort_by { |i| weights[i] }
  #=> [2, 0, 1]
str_arr.values_at(*a)
  #=> ["rob", "james", "blake"]
```

See [Array#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at) and [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).

Comment: `O(n*log(n))` is boring. Here's a nice `O(n!)` solution : `str_arr.permutation.to_a[weights.permutation.to_a.index(weights.sort)]` ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have two arrays that are 100% linked to each other, you should use a Hash :

```
str_arr = ["james", "blake", "rob"]
weights = [4, 7, 1]

weights = str_arr.zip(weights).to_h
# {"james"=>4, "blake"=>7, "rob"=>1}
```

You can just sort_by value then :

```
str_arr = ["james", "blake", "rob"]
weights = [4, 7, 1]

weights = str_arr.zip(weights).to_h

p weights.sort_by{|k, v| v}.map(&:first)
#=> ["rob", "james", "blake"]
```